# How to show Contents.Category array in object using .then

Tags: angular, typescript

I get this JSON

```
[
        {
            "Id": "15",
            "Category": "Our Values,WIDE",
        },
        {
            "Id": "19",
            "Category": "Art,History,Culture",
        },
        {
            "Id": "20",
            "Category": "Our Values,WIDE",
        },{.......}
    ]
```

from `this.CrewDataContents` below:

```
LoadData() {
    this.dataService.GetData(0, 3).then(models => {
        this.CrewData = models;
        this.CrewDataContents = models.reduce((r, { Contents }) => {
            Contents.forEach(o => r.push({ ...o }));
            return r;
        }, []);
        console.log(this.CrewDataContents );
    });
}
```

From `this.CrewDataContents` I want to get only Category.

Can you share with me any idea please? How to get Category from function below? I tried to use `.filter` and `.find` but nothing happens.

Comment: Hey @A. You want category from crewDataContents ??

Comment: Hi, Yes I want category from crewDataContents

Comment: can you post what your crewDataContents look like ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats it:

```
const jsonData = [
        {
            "Id": "15",
            "Category": "Our Values,WIDE",
        },
        {
            "Id": "19",
            "Category": "Art,History,Culture",
        },
        {
            "Id": "20",
            "Category": "Our Values,WIDE",
        }
    ]
var categoryData:String[] = [];
jsonData.forEach(element => {
    categoryData.push(element.Category);
})
console.log(categoryData);
```

Output:

> ["Our Values,WIDE", "Art,History,Culture", "Our Values,WIDE"]

So all you have to do, inside you .then function, you get the array, in my example the array you get from your backend is jsonData. Iterate over it, access the Category field and push that into a new array.